# Chaining promises in class

Tags: javascript, class, promise

I have class in which I'm trying to chain promises like this:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.driver = []
  }
  test() {
    this.method1()
    .then(this.method2)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('all done', this.driver)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong', err);
    });
  }
  method1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.driver.push('0');
        resolve();
      },200)
    });
  }
  method2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.driver.push('1');
        resolve();
      },200)
    });
  }
}

let instance = new Parent();
instance.test();
```

but `method2` is causing error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'driver' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `method2` here

```
.then(this.method2)
```

`method2` losses its binding to `this`

Try

```
.then(x => this.method2(x))
```

Or

```
.then(this.method2.bind(this))
```

Comment: Ok and when I have chain like above how I can pass some variable through resolve?

Answer (score 0):

It is occuring because you are passing a method to the `then` callback and `this` gets redefined. To keep `this` pointing at the instance of `Parent` use an arrow function in the `then` callback.

There are other ways to do this, see the excellent answer from this previous question: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1260204)

#### Your Code with Arrow Function

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.driver = []
  }
  test() {
    this.method1()
    .then(() => this.method2())
    .then(() => {
      console.log('all done', this.driver)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong', err);
    });
  }
  method1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.driver.push('0');
        resolve();
      },200)
    });
  }
  method2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.driver.push('1');
        resolve();
      },200)
    });
  }
}

let instance = new Parent();
instance.test();
```